# Make browser always in focus but not "on top" of other apps

Tags: javascript, events, browser, focus

I would like to know if there's a way to have the browser always in focus listening javascript events but not "on top" of another apps, can anyone tell me please? Thank you.

Comment: What? You mean you want to hi-jack events from another app?

Comment: i want to play a game but at the same time i want to capture if a key is pressed while i'm playing, and no, i don't want to hijack i'm just making an app that almost require that to not annoy people that uses it

Comment: In the browser with regular privileges, that's not possible. You'd have to make the focused app, or some deamon in the OS, send your app an event.